# How do I specify linker flags to be used in shared library build [cmake]

Tags: cmake, meego

I am running a build using cmake using the Meego 1.2 toolchain (long story).  This particular toolchain requires the `--sysroot` option to be used to find any libraries it requires.

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fpermissive")
set (CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "--sysroot=${INTEL_GRAPHICS_SDK_BASE}/sdk")
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
```

These options allow the cmake initial compiler checks to pass, but when producing a shared library during the build it looks like ld is being called without any of the options specified.

Is there a different cmake variable that needs to be set to specify the `sysroot` for shared libraries?

The error I am getting is

```
/usr/lib/madde/linux-i686/toolchains/meego-1.2-sdk-ia32-toolchain-1.0-linux_i686/i586-meego-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/i586-meego-linux-gnu/4.5.1/../../../../i586-meego-linux-gnu/bin/ld: crti.o: No such file: No such file or directory
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe you need `link_directories(${PATH_TO_crti.o})`?

Comment: is it cross compilation? in fact --sysroot is g++ flag. also you could try to use -Wl g++ option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS` CMake option (set by passing `-DCMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS='-L/some/path'` or any linker flags you need to your cmake invocation). For the (very brief) reference, see: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS.html#cmake-shared-linker-flags.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using cross compiler tool chain, why not just set **CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER** and pass those `--sysroot=` options to g++ (or gcc) directly?

There's also a flag named **CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS** with below explanation:

```
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS

   Linker flags used to create executables.

   Flags used by the linker when creating an executable.
```